# No /dev/sd for my hard drive?

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive

I recently tried to install lubuntu on an external hard drive and it had an error(just my luck).

I thought everything was fine, so I went to gparted to reset the partitions for use with Windows.  It showed 3 devices even though all there physically is was 1 device. So I rebooted and now it wouldn't show up what so ever (this is a 1TB drive so I was kinda mad).

It wasn't recognized in Windows so I googled around for a solution, and came to the Ubuntu rescue remix. I read that I should do the command `sudo lshw -C disk -short` and this gave me a table and to my surprise there is no /dev/sda or whatever letter -- it's blank.

It does read that the drive is there and it has a "H/W path"(whatever that is) ; this path is "/0/a/0.0.0". Long story short, my drive is useless in now -- I'm a bit of a noob and don't know what to do from here. Is there a way to get my drive back in a usable state?

If this helps any (`sudo lshw`) :

> ```
>   *-disk UNCLAIMED
>       description: SCSI Disk
>          product: My Passport 0730
>          vendor: WD
>          physical id: 0.0.0
>          bus info: scsi@3:0.0.0
>          version: 1015
>          serial: WX51A41X4251
>          configuration: ansiversion=6
> ```

Comment: check /var/log/syslog for the section where it detects that device?

Comment: Can you mount `/dev/sg1` or `/dev/sg2`? Errors?

Comment: sg isn't a valid disk device.  Also please edit your information into your question instead of linking to pastebin in a comment.  This is odd.  You might try `sudo -s` then `echo 3 0 0 > /sys/bus/scsi/drivers/sd/bind` or maybe 3 0 0 1, and check dmesg after for any new information.

Answer (score 1):

Try using Testdisk to find the drive. (Available as a download or on Parted Magic).  You may be able to recover lost partition information and reset it to get the drive going again.